# Fibonacci Sunflower spirals

Tags: plotting

Counting the clockwise and counterclockwise spirals that reach the outer edge, and we find a pair of numbers from the Fibonacci sequence: 34 and 55, or 55 and 89, or, with very large sunflowers: 89 and 144.

How can one sketch these symmetrical spirals in a plane? It requires the $r-\theta$ polar relation. The interpolating function for continuous polar curve is:

```
FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[n]]
=((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n Cos[n π])/Sqrt[5]
```

Comment: You have seen [this](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/) already, no?

Comment: I didn't !  It is marvelous. Shall I keep this or delete it ?

Comment: If you know now how to answer your question, it would be good to write an answer instead.

Comment: Thanks, shall attend to it a bit later.

Comment: Also look at the "neat example" for `GoldenAngle` in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoldenAngle.html